# Handling multi quantity inapp purchase in Google play billing

Tags: android

I am working on an app with inapp purchase that should be able to handle multiple quantity purchase.
I have enable the multiple quantity check box in play console as well as created and activated a template. However, this does not produce the multi quantity in the purchase dialog.
My question is how or what piece of code should be added to allow the add or minus quantity dialog.

Am a newbie to android development

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also searching this code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).